# In Django ,css file is not loaded

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Please tell me why static file can not be read.
I can read an image file but I can not read css and js file.
I see related questions elsewhere, but I can't solve them so I ask.

```
#settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'bootstrap4',
    'myapp.apps.MyappConfig',
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets'),
)
```

My directory structure.

```
Projects
-assets
    —css
        —style.css
    —image
    —js
        —style.js
-media
-projects
    —__init__.py
    —settings.py
    —urls.py
    —wigs.py
-myapp
    —migrations
    —__init__.py
    —admin.py
    —apps.py
    —models.py
    —tests.py
    —views.py
```

base.html

```
#html
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
{% load bootstrap4 %}
{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript jquery='slim' %}

<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/sawarabigothic.css" rel="stylesheet" >

    <link href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Myapp</title>
    {% include "navi.html" %}
</head>
<body>
  {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  </div>
  <script src="{% static 'js/style.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Although it is not here, the image file can be load.

```
<div class="text-center" style="background-image: url({% static 'image/back-image.jpg' %});">
```

addimage:
[image]

Comment: Can you load the file if you go to the the file's url from browser - `127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/style.css`?

Comment: @xyres yes,I can.

Comment: This is very strange. If you can access your file using the url, then the browser should also be able to load it. Do you see any errors in your browser's console? Also, what value do you see in `href` (check it by *Inspect Element*).

Comment: I understand the cause.
According to Chrome, "static / css / style.css" was loaded. Changing the "assets folder" to "static folder" will solve the problem, but is there a problem with my "STATICFILES_DIRS"?

Comment: No, the name of the folder doesn't really matter because you have configured it in `STATICFILES_DIRS`. What is the value of `Content-Type` header for *style.css* file in your browser's network log?

Comment: @xyres I don't know which one, but is it correct with the added image?

Comment: set STATIC_ROOT

Comment: @kan This image only shows JS files. Select `CSS` tab and update the image.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code , you shoulde you css link with "./static/css/style.css"

```
#html
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
{% load bootstrap4 %}
{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript jquery='slim' %}

<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/sawarabigothic.css" rel="stylesheet" >

    <link href="./static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Myapp</title>
    {% include "navi.html" %}
</head>
<body>
  {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  </div>
  <script src="{% static 'js/style.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But the `{% static ... %}` tag automatically does that; you don't need to hard code the file's url. It's not a good practice.

Comment: I tried it, but the result does not change.
I changed 'static' to 'assets' and tried.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the development server (ie './manage.py runserver') then you need to include the following in your `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

If running in production, make sure you've run `./manage.py collectstatic`

And within `settings.py`, make sure you've specified `STATIC_ROOT`

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in your settings.py file

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

After that add below code in your main project urls.py

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Hope, it will solve your problem.